# Buscar elementos usando como filtro un subdocumento en mongoose, Nodejs, MongoDB

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

He estado aprendiendo *Nodejs* y *MongoDB*, pero ahora he estado atascado en un tema de búsqueda usando como filtro un subdocumento. Tengo el siguiente esquema diseñado como modelo:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const estadoPedidoSchema = new Schema({
  pedidoId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Pedido'
  },
  creado: {
    status: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
    },
    observacion:{
      type: String,
      default: "Pedido creado correctamente"
    }
  },
  pago: {
    status: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    observacion:{
      type: String,
      default: null
    }
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('EstadoPedido', estadoPedidoSchema);
```

Ahora estoy tratando de hacer una búsqueda de todos los documentos que en el campo **creado** tengan como **status** un valor **Booleano** de **true**. Estaba tratando de hacer de la siguiente forma pero creo que no es la correcta y la verdad es que no me funciona a mi:

```js
const estadosPedido = await EstadoPedido.find({
  creado: {
    status: true
  }
});
```

La verdad es que estaba indagando y vi algo como búsquedas usando como filtros subdocumentos pero no entendí muy bien ese tema, si alguien me podría ayudar o guiar le agradecería de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea realizar una búsqueda en una colección de MongoDB usando como filtro un campo de un subdocumento (documento anidado). Sin embargo, al intentar con este filtro:

```js
const estadosPedido = await EstadoPedido.find({
  creado: {
    status: true
  }
});
```

no se obtiene ningún resultado.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución es simple, cuando deseamos realizar consultas sobre documentos de cualquier colección, usando como filtro un campo de un documento anidado, debemos pasar el valor del mismo como una cadena usando [notación de punto](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/document/#dot-notation).

De esta forma, el documento de filtro debe ser escrito así:

```js
{
  'creado.status': true
}
```

Si el campo a usar como filtro estuviera aún anidado otro nivel, usaríamos igualmente notación de punto para representar dicho nivel de profundidad:

```js
{
  'nivel_1.nivel_2.creado.status': true
}
```

Dicho esto, podemos hacer la consulta de la siguiente forma:

```js
const estadosPedido = await EstadoPedido.find({ 'creado.status': true });
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema